# How to keep partitions created before, for group by

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame, which I repartitioned with `repartitionByRange` or `custom-partitioner`.
Now, I'm operating `Group By` on this DataFrame, but the `GroupBy` causes a new repartition - hash partitioning on the columns selected to group by.

I was wondering how can you **keep your original created partitions for `GroupBy`**. Of course the partitions should be partitioned by the selected columns to group by, but **how can I determinate a different hashing strategy for group by**?